# Filtering tracks by streamable in Soundcloud

Tags: soundcloud

When calling this api:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?offset=0&q=ben+pearce&filter=streamable&order_by=hotness&consumer_key=[XXX]
```

I get a track that is NOT streamable, even though I've added &filter=streamable to the request. Am I doing it wrong?